# Where does emacs Predictive Mode store its dictionaries?

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I know I installed Predictive Mode correctly, because it works. However, I have a large file I want to turn into a custom dictionary, and I can't do it. First, I gave it the proper formatting, and tried to call it from within emacs. No go -- it won't acknowledge its existence. Then I tried pasting the entries into the main dictionary. That also didn't work -- Predictive Mode doesn't actually read from that file. Then, I tried creating a new dictionary, but it won't import the file. It just says "wrong type error." Meanwhile, in the process of creating the hypothetical new dictionary, I created a file, but now that file is nowhere to be found.

So, both the main dictionary, and the (empty) new one are hidden away somewhere, and I'm pulling my hair out trying to find it.

Comment: Please provide a link when asking about a third-party library.

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? http://www.dr-qubit.org/predictive/predictive-user-manual/html/Dictionaries.html#Dictionaries

Comment: I've been over the manual at length. That's where I learned how to (try to) create a new dictionary, etc.  But it doesn't tell you what to do when you hit roadblocks. For example, here's the error I get when trying to import a file into a new dictionary:

dictree-insert: Wrong type argument: sequencep,

Comment: Never mind. I'll go with auto-complete.